# Trouble Excluding Nodes from Graph

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

### Set-Up

I'm very new to graph databases and neo4j/cypher and I'm having a hard time understanding how to exclude various pieces from my results. Below is an image of my graph. Every node and every relationship has an `activeFrom` and `activeTo` property to allow me to view the graph as it existed at any given point in history.

```
MATCH (:Collective:Company)<-[tree *0..4]-(downline:Collective) RETURN downline
```

[image: graph visualization]

(Any relationship with a date indicates it's already, or scheduled (future date) to expire. No date or future date means it's active.).

---

### Question

My ultimate goal here is to view this same graph, minus all expired nodes and relationships. Right now, I'm trying to build the query that will let me see that and am failing :(

What I'm not understanding is why:

1. `Region5`'s relationship to `Company1` is still active... why isn't company showing up? (shouldn't the 0-length path bring the company back like in the first image?)
2. Both `Office5` and `Office27` have expired relationships, so why are they still in the result?
3. Offices 1, 2, 6, 9, and 11 are active nodes, but have no active relationships, so why are they being returned? (my GUESS here is that my 2nd `WHERE` clause (branch filter) is filtering out the relationships, but not the nodes they associate, but I'm not sure how to do it differently)

.

```
MATCH (:Collective:Company)<-[tree *0..4]-(downline:Collective)
WHERE
    // -- node(s) are active
    downline.activeFrom <= '2015-08-31 23:59:59'
    AND (downline.activeTo IS NULL OR downline.activeTo > '2015-08-31 23:59:59')
UNWIND tree AS branch
WITH branch, downline
WHERE
    // -- branch is active
    branch.activeFrom <= '2015-08-31 23:59:59'
    AND (branch.activeTo IS NULL OR branch.activeTo > '2015-08-31 23:59:59')
RETURN downline
```

[image]

### Bonus

I've set up a neo4j sandbox with this data for you guys to play with if needed. **Please be mature with this, as I don't know how to make it read only. Please don't go deleting data and messing things up for other people. I'm also personally paying for this cloud instance, so please don't abuse the VM/resources :)**

You can access it here: (sorry, removed for security purposes now that question has been answered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your questions, I'm trying to piece together what you require and I understand that you want to return paths that contain all active nodes and relationships. This is because you've asked about Office 27 and Office 5 which are both active nodes, but their single relationship to region 5 is inactive, so you do not want the paths between Office 27->Region 5 and Office 5->Region 5.

Office 2 however, is active, and it has an active relationship to region 4(also active). Region 4 has an inactive relationship to Company 1, so since you don't expect Office 2 in the results, I'm assuming it's because it has the inactive relationship in the entire path?

If this is the case, here's a query that hopefully does what you want-

```
MATCH p=(:Collective:Company)<-[tree*0..4]-(downline:Collective)
WHERE
  ALL(x in relationships(p) WHERE x.activeFrom <= '2015-08-31 23:59:59'
  AND (x.activeTo IS NULL OR x.activeTo > '2015-08-31 23:59:59'))
  AND ALL(x in nodes(p) WHERE x.activeFrom <= '2015-08-31 23:59:59'
  AND (x.activeTo IS NULL OR x.activeTo > '2015-08-31 23:59:59'))
RETURN p
```

This makes sure that every relationship and every node in a path is active. To bring back Office 2,1, change ALL to ANY and you'll see those back in the results because the path is now partially active.

BTW, you could also set up your graph at http://console.neo4j.org/?init=0 and share it

Comment: Ooh, this looks like a pretty good answer :) Thanks for the tip about the neo console :) Could you help me understand why the query I wrote didn't do what I expected?

Comment: It's a bit weird because you want to filter based on the path, but you've kind of split it up into nodes and then only relationships- if you do MATCH (:Collective:Company)<-[tree *0..4]-(downline:Collective)
WHERE
    // -- node(s) are active
    downline.activeFrom <= '2015-08-31 23:59:59'
    AND (downline.activeTo IS NULL OR downline.activeTo > '2015-08-31 23:59:59')
UNWIND tree AS branch return branch,downline you'll see what's getting passed to the next filter after the WITH.